# How to use Java stream map with filters and optional?

Tags: java, spring, java-stream

Basically what I want to do is following code(I will get system param and will check if it is not null then if the current system on the code is not equal to that then set the dbName as parameter)

```
if (Objects.nonNull(query.getSystem())) {
            if (!query.getSystem().equals(dbContextHolder.getCurrentDb().toString())) {
                dbContextHolder.setCurrentDb(Enum.valueOf(DbTypeEnum.class, query.getSystem()));
            }
        }
```

I also want if the currentDb system is null then return null. What I try to do is something like

```
var res = Optional.ofNullable(dbContextHolder.getCurrentDb().toString())
                .map(String::toString)
                .filter(s -> !s.equals(dbType))
                .orElse(Optional.ofNullable(dbType).orElse(null));
```

But as you see it is wrong and not working. How can I achieve that *if parameter dbType is not equal to getCurrentDb then call the method setDbType(paramDbType) if they are equal then return one of them if currentDb is null then return null*.

Comment: Why not just use a simple if/else block?

Comment: `map(String::toString)` does nothing since you already have a String. `Optional.ofNullable(dbType).orElse(null)` does nothing either, it returns the value of `dbType`. What do you mean by “_it is wrong and not working_”? Also note [Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks)’ [Rule #4: “It’s generally a bad idea to create an Optional for the specific purpose of chaining methods from it to get a value”](https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14?t=1678)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reducing your problem down I just realized that you always want the value of `query.getSystem()` to be the context, therefore:

I reduced your code like this:

```java
MockDbTypeEnum newMethod(MockQuery query, MockDbContextHolder dbContextHolder) {
    return Optional
            .ofNullable(query.getSystem())
            .map(MockDbTypeEnum::valueOf)
            .orElse(null);
}

MockDbTypeEnum oldMethod(MockQuery query, MockDbContextHolder dbContextHolder) {

    if (Objects.nonNull(query.getSystem())) {
        if (!query.getSystem().equals(dbContextHolder.getCurrentDb().toString())) {
            dbContextHolder.setCurrentDb(Enum.valueOf(MockDbTypeEnum.class, query.getSystem()));
        }

        return dbContextHolder.getCurrentDb();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Also here are the mocks and tests I used to prove these methods are functionally the same for your purposes:

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource(value = {
        "PSQL, PSQL, PSQL",
        "PSQL, SQL, PSQL",
        "SQL, SQL, SQL",
        "SQL, PSQL, SQL",
        "null, SQL, null",
        "null, PSQL, null"
}, nullValues = {"null"})
void test(String system, MockDbTypeEnum currentDb, MockDbTypeEnum expectedResult) {
    MockQuery query = new MockQuery(system);
    MockDbContextHolder dbContextHolder = new MockDbContextHolder(currentDb);

    MockDbTypeEnum result = oldMethod(query, dbContextHolder);
    assertEquals(expectedResult, result);

    MockDbTypeEnum newResult = newMethod(query, dbContextHolder);
    assertEquals(expectedResult, newResult);
}

enum MockDbTypeEnum {
    PSQL,
    SQL
}

static class MockQuery {

    private final String system;

    public MockQuery(String system) {
        this.system = system;
    }

    public String getSystem() {
        return system;
    }

}

static class MockDbContextHolder {

    private MockDbTypeEnum currentDb;

    public MockDbContextHolder(MockDbTypeEnum currentDb) {
        this.currentDb = currentDb;
    }

    public MockDbTypeEnum getCurrentDb() {
        return currentDb;
    }

    public void setCurrentDb(MockDbTypeEnum currentDb) {
        this.currentDb = currentDb;
    }

}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize the if clause was only there to see if the db system needs to change, and doesn't really functionally do anything.